# Redirect to request URL after redirect for authentication using Filter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, action-filter

We have an application that need user to authenticate in order to use. We have implemented this using a custom action filter attribute.

This is the filter we are using.

```
public class AuthFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public AuthFilter()
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var cacheKey = "user-session";
        var isValidAuth = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString(cacheKey);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(isValidAuth))
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Authentication" }));
        }
    }
}
```

This is how call the filter

```
[AuthFilter]
public IActionResult Overview()
{
    return View();
}
```

We are using this `AuthFilter` in multiple places. After login we need to redirect the user to the page user originally requested.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: I think you should read up on authentication and authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-2.1. In your app, configure authentication. Then you can use standard built-in authorization components to control access.

Comment: @juunas Thanks for your input, i will check this.

Comment: I really do suggest this with the best intentions :) You will save yourself a lot of headaches by using the components of the framework instead of building your own :)

Comment: @juunas, The thing is really didn't thought about using existing features, I'm already looking in to the link you provided so the issue can be solved easily.

Comment: If you need more advice, join the .NET Core Slack if you haven't already: http://tattoocoder.com/aspnet-slack-sign-up/

Comment: @juunas thank you for the link, i will use it wisely :)